# Date Field in SharePoint(On-Prem) list returns Previous day Date instead of current date in MS-Flow(Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-2019

Issue: We have created a MS Flow to trigger, when an item is created in SharePoint list (On-Prem) and in flow (On-Cloud) returns the date field value as One day before of actual date value.

eg: If I have a Due Date field in SharePoint List and created new items with a Due Date valueas 6/28/2019, but at the time of Flow trigger it returns the Due Date value as 6/27/2019.

And I have configured the Sharepoint App server(On-Prem), Database server(On-Prem), MS-Flow (Online) to IST time zone, but still I'm facing the issue.

Regards,
Tharma KS

Comment: There's a similar issue in SharePoint Search where search internally uses GMT for date comparisons. Do you have this problem for all ranges of times within a date?

Comment: In SharePoint there is no issue, it shows the actual date and no issue in search. but In flows, it returns the One day before date of actual date.